# importing numpy -c extensions failed. while creating .exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I have a .py file that I created a .exe file from using pyinstaller. The app is raising an error that importing numpy -c extensions failed. [Link to error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK4gw.png)

I am trying to implement a CIC flowmeter in an app. I have the whole code in one single .py file. It is running fine when executing the python file. But when I tried to convert it into a .exe file, I am getting this error.